# Maven: Could not transfer - Not authorized

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I want to import the artifact "net.ozyris.core:api:0.1:" from my private repository: https://nexus.ozyris.net/repository/ozyris-releases/

But, when I try `mvm install` I got this error:

```
Could not transfer artifact net.ozyris.core:api:pom:0.1 from/to ozyris-releases (https://nexus.ozyris.net/repository/ozyris-releases/): Not authorized
```

settings.xml

```xml
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>ozyris-releases</id>
            <username>username</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
</settings>
```

pom.xml

```xml
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ozyris-releases</id>
            <url>https://nexus.ozyris.net/repository/ozyris-releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.ozyris.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>api</artifactId>
            <version>0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Username and password are valid & have access to the repository (open the url on my browser, copy and paste form settings.xml and it's works)

What should I do?

Comment: Is you settings.xml file at the correct location? Can be checked via `mvn -X ...` with the first 50 lines or so you will find which settings.xml etc. will really read...

Comment: @khmarbaise correct location because I use others repositories and it's works fine

Comment: Then your credentials are wrong ...wrong encoded etc. ...